# Posting data from a single table row asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm still quite new to MVC and I'm wondering if I am implementing the following in a correct way.

I have a table that is being build in a foreach loop. On each row there is a dropdown box. I attached an eventlistener to the dropdown for on change using jQuery. In the onchange event I post my data. Now my biggest concern is how to retrieve the data for the row that was changed. I'm currently using a hiddenfield for this. In webforms, this would have been a simple repeater and than all the data would be available on postback.
Please find a basic version of my loop below.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bar)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Foo, new SelectList(item.Foos, "Id", "Name", item.FooID), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control ddlFoo" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Bar, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "hfBar" })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

So is this the correct approach? Or what would be a better way?
Thank you for helping out a MVC newbie

********************UPDATE*********************
My controller method is as follows:

```
public JsonResult UpdateFooBar(int FooID, int BarID)
    {
        if(dosomething(FooID, BarID)
            return Json(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        else
            return Json(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
```

The jQuery is a simple ajax post. All works fine, I'm just not sure if this is the best way of doing things, since DOM changes could pottentially break the jQuery script

```
$('.ddlFoo').change(function () {
    var BarID = $(this).next(".hfBar").val();
    var FooID = $(this).val();
    var FooBar= {"BarID": BarID , "FooID ": FooID};
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UpdateFooBar", "FooBar")',
        data: JSON.stringify(FooBar),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Show the controller method your posting to and your jquery

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: Looks OK to me, although your creating invalid html because the dropdownlists and hidden inputs have duplicate `id` attributes so suggest you add `new { id = "" }` so that the `id` is omitted. You can also omit the hidden input and use `new { data_ID = item.Bar }` in the `DropDownListFor()` and then retrieve in the the script using `var BarID = $(this).data('ID')` so DOm changes would not have any impact